FFmpeg RTSP Recording: Video Timestamp Does not Match With Recorded MP4 File Timestamp
I'm currently testing by streaming a 30 fps example flv video using a local Happy-Time RTSP server.
This is the flv file i am streaming with RTSP:

I recorded the video with below ffmpeg command:
ffmpeg -i rtsp://127.0.0.1:6555/test30fps.flv -c copy test30fps.mp4

The resulting video appears visually satisfactory, yet there's a discrepancy between the displayed time on the video and the actual duration of the video file. Although the MP4 file duration is correct (endRecordingTimeMs-startRecordingTimeMs= mp4 file duration), the time displayed within the video does not synchronize precisely with the file's time. Notably, this disparity escalates as the video progresses.
I anticipate the time text overlaid on the video and the file's time to align seamlessly. However, a few seconds of divergence are noticeable, gradually expanding over the video's duration.

Why does this occur and is there any way to fix this?
